# Set different References to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have this database structure:
[image]

And at the time I have following Code:

```
final DatabaseReference messagesRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users/").child(firebase_user_uid + "/").child("chats/");
    messagesRef.keepSynced(true);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatListMediation> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatListMediation>().setQuery(messagesRef, parser).build();

    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatListMediation, MessageViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            final int layout = viewType == TYPE_INACTIVE ? R.layout.item_chatlist : R.layout.item_chatlist_selected;
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new MessageViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int position, final ChatListMediation chatListMediation) {
            viewHolder.chatKey = chatListMediation.getChatkey();

        }
    };
```

So and here we go. The FirebaseRecyclerAdapter I set up for the following `FirebasedatabseReference`: `users/firebase_user_uid/chats`. So here I get a List of Chatkeys.  But now I need something who goes into the `FirebaseDatabseReference`  "chats/chat_key"  and read the info there. For example the "chattype" or  "createdTime" . At first, I had a lot of addValueEventListener at the different things I want but I think that's, not the best an fastest way. Maybe a second `FirebaseReycyclerAdapter`? Or can I switch the FirebaseDatabseRefernce of the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` during the runtime? I don't know who to solve.
I hope you understand my Problem and can help me. If there are any Questions you have let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change this line of code:

```
DatabaseReference messagesRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users/").child(firebase_user_uid + "/").child("chats/");
```

with

```
DatabaseReference messagesRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference
    .child("users")
    .child(firebase_user_uid)
    .child("chats");
```

As you can see, I have removed the `/` otherwise your reference would have contain double `/`. You can also get your reference in a short way like this:

```
DatabaseReference messagesRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference
    .child("users/" + firebase_user_uid + "/chats/");
```

I also recommend you use a `Query` like this:

```
Query query = messagesRef.orderByChild("active").equalsTo(true);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how I can get the data I want from the other reference?

Comment: Which other reference? With this query you can get all the chats within a particular user.

Comment: I want to get the ref "chats/chat_key" information maybe with a firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: Firebase adapters in FirebaseUI show only the child nodes of the location or the query that you bind them to. There is no feature to show lower-level descendants or other locations at all using a single reference. You need to create another one or if needed a combined one.

Comment: How to make a combined one? You mean two for one List?

Comment: I mean nested queries. So you get some data from the database that is used in another query, to get other data.